# What is the difference between using "::std" or including "using namespace std" in the header?

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces

I currently define a string `ID` inside a class `Return_Class` for this to work I need to use "namespace." (I'm working in Qt.)

When I put `using namespace std;` my code functions perfectly, however when I remove `using namespace std;` and edit my class to...

```
class Return_Class : public QString
{
public:
    static std::QString ID;
};
```

...my code get the error message "QString in namespace "std" does not name a type"

I know that using std:: is considered better practice, but I'm confused as to why it doesn't work it my case? Is my syntax for the string wrong? Thanks

Comment: `QString` is not in the `std` namespace. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: I suggest you learn what namespace actually is.

Comment: Btw. it´s "syntax", not "sin-tax"

Comment: @deviantfan He was just trying to be funny :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `QString`, and `QString` is not from `std namespace`. When you directly type `std::QString` you will get an error, because `QString` is not defined in `std namespace`, but when you type `using namespace std`,  You can use everything from `std namespace` without directly typing `std` (what is defined in that namespace), but not `QString` because definition of `QString` is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Qstring is not a part of the namespace, hence you are getting the error.

BTW , are you sure you wanted to use `static std::QString ID;`
or is it **`static std::string ID;`**

And regarding difference between using "::std" or "using namespace std"
It is always better to use "::std", because what if you are using two different namespaces, and they both have a function named `func()`. It will be ambiguous.

one more thing to note is that you should never put

```
using namespace std
```

In a header file, as it can propagate to all files that include that header file, even if they don't want to use that namespace.